# How to embed the iPython Notebook in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ipython, embed, jupyter-notebook

I have an iPython Notebook that needs to be embedded into my Rails application.

I have two options for doing it:

1. Just rendering the `.ipynb` file on the page (like GitHub does)
2. (desirable option) Embed the notebook with the kernel and interactive elements.

The notebook I have is quite large and it uses python-specific tricks and libraries, so rewriting it into the ruby notebook is not a good option.

---

So, how can one render the iPython Notebook file on the web page (like GitHub does) or how to embed the fully-functional iPython Notebook into the Rails application?

Comment: The static render as seen in Github is created by [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert), which you can run as a subprocess and embed the output. Be careful with security if it's user-generated content. For the interactive Notebook application, the only reasonable approach would be to run as a separate server and use it in an iframe, or on a separate page (perhaps behind a proxy to integrate the URLs).